# Cannot access templates running Spring Boot with JAR

Tags: maven, spring-boot, command-line, jar, thymeleaf

I have to run a Spring Boot on the command line using its `JAR`. I've seen already many topics about the "fat JAR", which I believe I have already created.

The program uses Spring Boot + Maven + Thymeleaf + Spring Security.

**The problem**

- Templates that are in the `templates` folder - i.e. `/resources/templates/<file>` are displayed correctly (I have `index.html`, `login.html` and `underConstruction.html` tested and working)
- Templates that are in subfolders - i.e. `/resources/templates/client/edit.html` or `/resources/templates/client/search.html` - fail to render with the following error shown on the browser

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Error resolving template "/client/add", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Changing Spring Security config to permit all requests on a given URL doesn't change anything, so I think it's not related to it.

**Running the app**

1. Using Maven: `./mvnw spring-boot:run` works fine
2. Using the `JAR`: `java -jar myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT0.jar` start correctly, but doesn't render the pages mentioned above

**Building the JAR**

- Executed `./mvnw clean package` or `./mvnw clean install`

There are 2 `JAR` files generated

1. `myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` with size of 42MB
2. `myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original` with size of 684K

**The pom.xml file** *(just a small snippet to show the plugin that generates the "fat JAR")*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

**A random Controller** *(just to have an idea of how their code is)*

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/client/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String search(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
        model.addAttribute("clients", new ArrayList<Client>());

        return "/client/search";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/client/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
        return "/client/edit";
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Is this the exact location `/resources/..*`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I found this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744 and ended up removing the slashes for the return statement in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is likely how you are returning the template names:

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

    //and you could just make this simpler, like:
    //@GetMapping("/search")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/client/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String search(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
        model.addAttribute("clients", new ArrayList<Client>());

        return "client/search"; //NOTE: no slash
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/client/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
        return "client/edit"; //NOTE: no slash
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this issue in Spring Boot github - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744 - and I thought it should be resolved by now.  I'm not sure this is the correct behaviour or if they should still fix it. Thank you!